# How to query Solr for a Collection's details, such as a Collections' config name?

Tags: solr

How can I query Solr, using the HTTP API, for information about a collection? I'm not talking about the collection's indexes, which I could query using the COLSTATUS command. I'm just talking about the basic details of a collection, which you can see when you click on a collection in the Solr web admin page, such as config name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When wondering where information provided in the web interface comes from, the easiest way is to bring up your browser's development tools and go to the Network section. Since the interface is a small Javascript application, it uses the available REST API in the background - the same that you'd query yourself.

Extensive collection information can be retrieved by querying:

```
/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=json
```

(Any `_` parameter is just present for cache busting).

This will return a list of all the collections present and their metadata, such as which config set they use and what shards the collection consists of. This is the same API endpoint that the web interface uses.

```
collections":{
  "aaaaa":{
    "pullReplicas":"0",
    "replicationFactor":"1",
    "shards":{"shard1":{
        "range":"80000000-7fffffff",
        "state":"active",
        "replicas":{"core_node2":{
            "core":"aaaaa_shard1_replica_n1",
            "base_url":"http://...:8983/solr",
            "node_name":"...:8983_solr",
            "state":"down",
            "type":"NRT",
            "force_set_state":"false",
            "leader":"true"}}}},
    "router":{"name":"compositeId"},
    "maxShardsPerNode":"1",
    "autoAddReplicas":"false",
    "nrtReplicas":"1",
    "tlogReplicas":"0",
    "znodeVersion":7,
    "configName":"_default"},
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
getConfigName(String collectionName){
    
    //provide the list of zookeeper instances   
    List<String> zkHosts = ""
    // get the solr cloud client
    CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder (zkHosts, Optional.empty 
    ()).build ();
    
    // get the config for the collection
    String configName = solrConnectionProvider.getCloudSolrClient().getZkStateReader().readConfigName(collectionName);
   return configName;
}
```

Please handle the exception(s) from your end.